# How to update a pandas dataframe column values from another dataframe based on a matching column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update the values of a specific column in a pandas dataframe from another dataframe. I have checked many posts on StackOverflow, but none worked for me.

Below is an example with the expected output:

**df1**

```
idx a1 b1   c1 d1 e1
12  4  x10  1  2  5
13  5  x2   3  5  4
14  6  x4   4  5  6
15  7  x13  7  9  2
```

**df2**

```
idx a2  b2 c2 d2 e2
1   x2  x1 2  2  4
2   x8  x2 5  7  8
3   x6  x4 6  9  5
4   x4  x7 6  8  9
```

**b1** is compared with **b2** and in case of matching **b1** should be updated with the value of **a2**. So, df1 should be updated as below.
**Update**: the tricky bit is that once comparing **b1** with **b2** is that **b2** should be updated with the value of **a2** not **b1**

**df1**

```
idx a1  b1   c1 d1 e1
12  4   x10  1  2  5
13  5   x8   3  5  4
14  6   x6   4  5  6
15  7   x13  7  9  2
```

Comment: `df1['b1'] = df1['b1'].map(df2.set_index('b2')['a2']).fillna(df1['b1'])`

Comment: @mozway, it didn't work and triggered the following error: `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: you didn't provide an index in you example, make sure it's unique, if not make it temporarily a column

Comment: Do you need `df1['b1'] = df1['b1'].map(df2.drop_duplicates('b2').set_index('b2')['a2']).fillna(df1['b1'])` ?